# How can window object properties be mocked in a karma/mocha test suite?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, webpack, karma-mocha

I'm using karma and mocha along with React's TestUtils to test a React application. One of the components that I'm testing imports a module with the following export:

`export const OPTIONS = window.__OPTIONS__;`

In my test, I am rendering the component into a virtual chrome browser in karma. I'm doing this via:
`let tree = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Component />);`

The render function of "Component" references something like `OPTIONS.someOption` and when the above test runs, it blows up and says `cannot read property 'someOption' of undefined.`

I tried 'mocking' the `__OPTIONS__` variable in the `before()` function (to set the value of it prior to the test running), but even after logging it out and seeing that it was in fact set, the value of it within my component module is still undefined. So it seems like webpack is bundling the modules prior to any of my test script actually running and thus it's always undefined.

Is there a way to have `window.__OPTIONS__` set to a value as though it would if it were contained in `<script>window.__OPTIONS__ = {};</script>` at the top of my page and thus being properly imported with a value in my component module?

I don't want to get into why I'm attaching the variable to the window object, since it's something I can't avoid in this case...It's a Salesforce specific reason. If I could avoid using that variable altogether I would.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a window object to global with `__OPTIONS__` in `beforeEach`:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    global.window = {
        __OPTIONS__: {}
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the `global` route, but to no avail...window was already always defined since karma was spinning up the Chrome browser. After messing around with logging in different areas, I confirmed the order of operations was 1. modules were bundled 2. test script ran. I added a log directly underneath the import statement in my component and then on the first line of my test script, and the log right after my import always reported undefined first.

Taking this, I backed up a step and looked at `tests.webpack.js`, which is in both `files` and `preprocessors` (webpack) in my karma config file. I added my variable declaration above the lines `var context = require.context('./src', true, /-test\.jsx?$/);` and `context.keys().forEach(context);` and it works fine now.